# Standalone Web Service authentication error

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, web, service

I current have a standalone web service and everything fine except when I try to use one of the methods from a remote machine.

I am using wcftestclient to test.

I get an authentication error message:

> "The caller was not authenticated by the service"

I can hit the web service from the remote machine the methods populate in wcftestclient however when I try to invoke it I get the authentication error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

This is my app.config file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <!-- This section is optional with the new configuration model
           introduced in .NET Framework 4. -->
      <service name="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CalculatorService" behaviorConfiguration="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- this endpoint is exposed at the base address provided by host: http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service  -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.ICalculator" />
        <!-- the mex endpoint is exposed at http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service/mex -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `includeExceptionDetailInFaults` to true? That might help point you in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the security Mode to none and try it

```
      <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        </security>
```

Comment: Thanks all is working now!! I created a client and added the web service and it created a app.config for me and it works like a charm! Thanks again